# Loop with delay in Qml

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, delay

I tried almost every solution from the internet, but nothing work. I want create a while (true) loop, with an delay about 20 ms per iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timer would be a better approach:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 320
    height: 260
    visible: true

    Timer {
        id: timer
        interval: 20
        running: false
        repeat: true
        property int returnedValue: 0
        onTriggered: {
            console.log("Loop iteration every 20ms");
            returnedValue = 12;
        }
        onReturnedValueChanged: {
            timer.stop();
            console.log("Stop loop wth:", returnedValue);
        }
    }

    function startTimer() {
        timer.running = true;
    }

    Button {
        text: "Click me"
        onClicked: startTimer()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I break out the timer?

Comment: Ok I found it out. But how can I call the timer inside a function.

Comment: I've updated my example. The timer is started int the function `startTimer`, now.

Comment: Thank you very much. I want return a value if a specific variable is not no 0. How can I return a value from timer?

Comment: The easiest way would be to store your value in property and stop the timer.

Comment: Can you give me an example. Sorry I'm very new with qt.